# Azure Slot Swapping: Configure WCF endpoint in Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-web-app-service, wcf-endpoint

I want to use Slot Swapping on Azure for a WCF Service. I know that we can do the appSettings directly in Azure. I couldn't find an option to configure the system.serviceModel/client, but for slot swapping i need 3 endpoint configurations, one on each slot I have

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://myservice-devslot.azurewebsites.net/ServiceName.svc" ... />
</client>
```

This would be the configuration for 1 slot, as it's shown in the address: dev-slot

Or is there an other approach to manage endpoints?

Comment: So you need a single `<endpoint>`-node with a different address per slot (= environment?) e.g. dev/test/integration/production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I configured the endpoint address through Code and added an EndPointAddress Key to the AppSettings. Now I can swap from TEST to INT etc by just do one click in Azure. Thanks everyone

```
        wcfServiceClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(endPointAddress);
```

Comment: I like this approach. Being able to use slot settings to set this value is a lot cleaner than having to perform transforms on the web.config in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For editing config files depending on the destination environment you're going to deploy the application to, you'd usually use [config transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As you're looking to so using azure, have a look at [this article](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/managing-multiple-windows-azure-web-site-environments-using-visual-studio-publishing-profiles) by [Brady Gaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28686/brady-gaster) as starting point. It describes the whole procedure quite detailed.

Comment: Ok, i got it. It's basically a transformation of config during the deployment. The Problem is, that i want to be able to swap between dev/test/integration/production. All deployments should go to dev, and whenever it passes, a swap should be the only thing to do. As I understood, this is the recommended way to handle Slots and Swap function.

Comment: Well, as a workaround you could put your endpoint address into a "regular" appSetting and have it [configured](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) via the azure management interface.